# Is it right to say "Only somebody can do something the best"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it right to say "Only somebody can do something the best"? Or instead, we should  say "Somebody can do something the best" or "only somebody can do something well"?

e.g.

"Only mathematics can give the most clear explanation to the question."

"Mathematics can give the most clear explanation to the question."

"Only mathematics can give a clear explanation to the question."

Comment: In its present form I think this question is unanswerable. None of the above are "credible" utterances. Using different words, what is it you *want* to convey?

Comment: updated, @FumbleFingers

Comment: Please give more context.

Comment: @mmb: The context is the examples.

Comment: Also, you should use "clearest" rather than "most clear".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: your comment sums it up perfectly.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the support. More particularly, thanks for calling my attention to the fact that this question doesn't actually have any answers. I think "number/proportion of unanswered question" is one of the factors taken into account when TPTB consider promoting SO "beta" sites to full status, so I'll move my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

OP's #1 is at the very least unusual - obviously *only **one*** can be the *clearest/biggest/smallest/whatever*, so it's both redundant and cumbersome to include the word *only*. But #2 and #3 mean different things.

With #2, it's possible many other disciplines can provide clear explanations (just *not quite **as** clear* as that provided by mathematics).

But #3 asserts that *no other disciplines at all* can give clear explanations.